# How do you choose between docker-ce and docker-engine?

Tags: docker

I started off needing to upgrade Docker on Ubuntu 14.04 and found https://askubuntu.com/questions/472412/how-do-i-upgrade-docker which requires me to make a choice.

Every reference I find compares docker-ce and docker-ee.

Here are a few references:

- https://docs.docker.com/install/
- https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/
- https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ee/ubuntu/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`docker-engine` was renamed to `docker-ce`. If you check current [installation instructions](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/#os-requirements):

> Older versions of Docker were called docker or docker-engine. If these are installed, uninstall them:
>
> `$ sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io`

Comment: Thankfully it's simple! My brain skips over any info it interprets as marketing speak. That kind of skimming gets me in trouble sometimes. But, with all the commercially sponsored Open Source products I use, there's really no other way to function.